# Java: Opening a file that is already open but has been updated

Tags: java, file

I am using java to write to a text file when a button is pressed.

I am writing to the file using:

```
FileWriter write = null;
    try {
        write = new FileWriter(fileLocation, false);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(write);
        print.printf("%s" + "%n", text);
        print.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            write.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Once it has been written to, I open the text file using:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(fileLocation));
```

This is fine if the text file is closed when the button is pressed. However, if the file is open, then the text file is changed, but the changes aren't shown when java 'opens' the file. Instead, it brings the already open text file to the front but does not update the contents.

Is there a way to show the new information?

Comment: how are you exactly modifying that file?

Comment: If you save the file. then when you open it you should get the saved content.

Comment: My problem is that when I ask java to open the file, if the file is already open, it simply brings the window to the front and does not actually update the information.

Comment: BTW, you might get a NPE in the write.close() if the FileWriter fails in the c'tor. You need to wrap it with if (write != null)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you are going to be able to fix this directly.

Java's Desktop class just doesn't have enough integration with the native OS to be able to determine if the file is already open, or to close whatever native application is displaying it.

You don't say what kind of file you are writing to, but perhaps you could write Java code to display it within your program, instead of just asking the native OS to "open" it. Then you'd have the control that you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is mostly expected behaviour - displaying files is left to system default text editor (Notepad most likely). It is clueless about any changes made to the file after it's started and there is no way to change that.

Possible solutions:

- enforce using a more up-to-date default text editor (like Notepad++) if that's feasable
- somehow kill default editor process (or close it more gracefully if you wish) to ensure your text file is opened again.
- write your own text display instead of relying on Desktop